# Fit app icon text in one line in android with Greek characters

Tags: android, android-icons

I am trying to type an app name in Greek, with 10 letters and when I test the app, the text of app icon is 9 characters in first line and 1 character in second line. When tested with 10 latin characters it is been displayed normal 10 characters in first line. Why?

Comment: paste ur code, and response

Comment: <string name="app_name">Καρδερινες</string>

Comment: because all characters are not equal in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is about the size of the font of different chars.
For example the size of an "m" is bigger than the size of an "l".

If you want all the chars to be the same size, you need to use a monospaced font. But for the device, not for the app you are developing.

But don´t worry about it, because every device is a different world. Ones will need two lines and other ones maybe need 3 lines. The way and size to represent your icon and the name of the app depends only on the device ..

Comment: How to use a monospaced font for an app icon text?

Comment: You can change the font in your own device in the settings, but you can't change the font of all devices that download your app. Then maybe in its devices the title will be in two lines.